# What can I do about small pools of water on my garage floor?

Tags: concrete, water

I just moved into this house and I have discovered about 20 different size "water" marks.  As I haven't parked my car in the garage - I would have noticed it sooner.  But what can I do for this problem.  My drains outside are not close to the house.

Comment: Is there actually water on the floor or just dark marks? If the later, it's possible they're oil stains.

Comment: Kitty liter (ground-up clay), is an excellent absorbent for oil spills. otherwise it's a garage; who cares?

Comment: If the water reaches a seam (either in the floor or at the wall floor intersection) this can cause problems with settling and such

Answer (score 3):

Your options are:

1. Do nothing.  A little bit of standing water on an unsealed concrete floor will seep away and vanish in a few hours to days.
2. Use a broom or squeegee and move the water outside or to a drain.
3. Place catch basins (if it comes from a drip above) or barriers (if it comes from the side over the floor) to prevent the water from standing on the floor.
4. Identify the source of the water and remedy it.

Comment: I would go with the do nothing option. It's a garage and if the water isn't infiltrating the rest of the house, I'd leave it alone.